# Prometheus metrics in my application after some time becomes too large and scrape latency becomes very high

Tags: prometheus

I have created a few metrics using different label combinations which keeps building up after a period of time and as a result, when Prometheus server scrapes the "/metrics" endpoint, the latency is too high with significantly large response size. This is causing an impact on the application performance to serve other requests.

I have read that Prometheus suggests against overuse of labels  ([Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels)). But, my question is, if there is a way we could clear the metrics from the client? Or, is it really recommended to clear them from the app?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a classic label cardinality issue, the solution is to avoid doing this in the first place. Prometheus is not an event-logging system, so must choose some of those labels to remove from the metric so that this doesn't happen.